# htaccess rewrite without query String

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have this old URL: `domain.com/site.html`
and I would like to do a RedirectPermanent to: `domain.com/site` (without .html)

But what actually happens is this: `domain.com/site?url=site.html`
I dont know why. Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: this config does not contain anything with `site.html`

Answer (score 0):

You receive the result you observer because that is exactly what you implemented.

Have a try with that instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301]
```

That rule set will work likewise in your http servers (virtual) host configuration or in dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files).

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately i get a 404 (for every page except for the startpage, root) if I try your code.

Comment: Well, obviously if you redirect to `/site` your service needs to be able to resolve that and respond to it. What means do you have in place to do so?

Comment: hm, not sure what to do. But with the original code the server responds and shows for example /site etc.

Comment: Well, you really should be able how your setup works! We cannot tell you, remember that we cannot look over your shoulder. What resource _does_ handle requests to `/site`? You really should find out, don't you think? It is _your_ site!

Comment: I am using (learning) with this framework: https://github.com/panique/huge. There is a .htaccess in the root and under /public. I just wrote this rule: `RewriteRule ^site.html /site [R=301,L]` and it does what i want. But I am not sure if this is a good way

Comment: Well, it is limited to the literal path `/site.html`. I obviously assumed you have multiple such paths and want to rewrite _the pattern_, not a single, individual path.